# Как правильно построить SEF (ЧПУ) для сайта из фильтров?

Tags: url, чпу

Предполагается, что категорий, под категорий нет. Есть только фильтр, в соответствии с которым выводятся результаты.

Хотелось бы отойти от GET параметров (/?param=1&param=2,3,4), это некрасиво, не ЧПУ и есть вероятность что поисковики не одобряют такое. К тому же, если поменять местами параметры, содержимое останется таким же, а ссылка поменяется, что по определению является дублем.

Но как и какой длинный (есть подозрение что поисковики не любят большие урлы) формировать ЧПУ, чтобы пользователь на выбирал штук 10-20 фильтров, по ним сформировалась ссылка (на лету в браузере) и ее могли поисковики индексировать, делиться такой ссылкой с друзьями. Чтобы от перемены мест фильтров, ссылка не менялась и не создавались дубликаты страниц.

Вопрос чисто теоретический, т.к. хочется просто понять грамотный принцип (подход) в таком случае. Мозги выворачиваются, так и не понял как это сделать.

Comment: Есть мнение, что поисковикам наплевать на ЧПУ/неЧПУ, главное содержание. А чтобы дублей не было можно указывать канонический url.

Comment: чпу он на то и чпу, чтобы быть понятным человеку, представьте, что вы человек - как вам было бы удобно вводить ваши параметры? как только ответите - так и делайте